# Imported lazy module with routes overrides other modules

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Im trying to import a lazy module IdCardModule into another lazy module named EmployeeModule, but when I try to open the EmployeeModule routes like 
 */employee/create*, it always opens the routes of the IdCardModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: EmployeesComponent,

    children: [
      { path: '', component: OverviewComponent },
      { path: 'create', component:CreateComponent}
    ]
  }
];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
      ],
      declarations: [
        EmployeesComponent,
        OverviewComponent,
        CreateComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        EmployeeDetailService
     ]})
    export class EmployeesModule { }
```

IdCardMododule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: IdCardComponent,

    children: [
      { path: '', component: OverviewComponent },
      { path: 'CreateComponent', component:CreateIdCardComponent}
    ]
  }
];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        IdCardModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        ICardComponent,
        OverviewComponent,
        CreateIdCardComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        IdCardService
     ]})
    export class IdCardsModule{ }
```

AppModule with childroutes

```
const routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './modules/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
    { path: 'employee', loadChildren: './modules/employees/employees.module#EmployeesModule', canActivate: [RouteGuard] },
    { path: 'idcard', loadChildren: './modules/identity-card/id-cards.module#IdCardsModule', canActivate: [RouteGuard] },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
     })
  ],
```

Comment: can you include the routes that lazyload IdCardMododule, and from what i see IdCardMododule have no route named `create`, so is there a redirecting route in your routing module ?

Comment: where is ur parent routing ? can u show ur parent routing?

Comment: oh sorry, updated my answer